# Horizontal Scroll Problem - No elements off

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an unwanted horizontal scroll on my website and I can't figure out why. I have a simple header that uses `display: flex`, `justify-content: center`, `marin-top: 5vh` and a padding on the logo and the burger. Further down it has a title that does `translate-x: 1em to 0em` when loading from the right, a text that does the same from the left and an image that does it again from the right. [Screenshot from my Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuTPB.jpg)

Code:

```js
// Loading animation
loading = document.querySelectorAll(".loading");

window.onload = function(element) {
  loading.forEach((link) => {
    link.classList.add("loaded");
  });
};
```

```css
.title {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-2em);
  transition: transform 3s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.3, 1), opacity 0.3s 0.5s ease-out;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.title.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0em);
}

.text {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-4em);
  transition: transform 4s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.3, 1), opacity 0.3s 0.5s ease-out;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.text.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.hero-image {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(1em);
  transition: transform 1s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.3, 1), opacity 0.1s 0.5s ease-out;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.hero-image.loaded {
  transform: translateX(0em);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-hero {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(1em);
  transition: transform 1s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.3, 1), opacity 0.1s 0.5s ease-out;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.mobile-hero.loaded {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile">
  <div>
    <h1 class="title loading">Michael Nussbaum</h1>
    <p class="text bottom loading">Zeit ist relativ, Zeit ist Geld</p>
  </div>
  <img src="img/daniel-portrait.png" class="mobile-hero loading" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're after, but if you want to stop horizontal overflow on a page you should be able to use this code:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I don't work with animated elements a lot, but I would imagine that the translateX is causing the unwanted scroll, which the overflow-x should help. Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thanks but i am already using overflow-x: hidden